# Routing error: trying to route a defined route in urls.py

Tags: django, url

I encountered a strange behavior of Django urls. Although forecast/upload url is defined in the urls.py, Django is saying

Page not found (404)

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/forecast/upload/
Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

polls/  
admin/  
forecast/ [name='index']  
forecast/ **forecast/upload/** [name='upload']  
forecast/ help.html [name='help']  

The current path, **forecast/upload/**, didn't match any of these.
```

Project url.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('forecast/', include('forecast.urls')),
]
```

Application urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    #url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
    path('forecast/upload/', views.upload, name="upload"),
    path('help.html', views.help, name="help"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified "forecast" twice; once at project level and once in the app. So your URL would be "forecast/forecast/upload".

Presumably, you don't want that, in which case you should remove the "forecast" from the pattern in the app urls.